# How to deserialize data records serialized with FOR XML AUTO in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, serialization

In my Microsoft SQL Server 2005 database I have data in column `WorkingDays` like :

```
<WorkingDays>
  <Day>2011-05-05</Day>
  <Day>2011-05-06</Day>
</WorkingDays>
```

How to deserialize them within T-SQL query to `DateTime` format?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, XmlContent XML)

INSERT INTO @TEST(XmlContent) VALUES('<WorkingDays>
  <Day>2011-05-05</Day>
  <Day>2011-05-06</Day>
</WorkingDays>')


SELECT 
    ID,
    WD.DAYS.value('(.)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'Day'
FROM 
    @TEST
CROSS APPLY 
    XmlContent.nodes('/WorkingDays/Day') AS WD(Days)
```

This gives me an output of:

```
ID    Day
1     2011-05-05 00:00:00.000
1     2011-05-06 00:00:00.000
```